# Need to match similarly titled filenames present in a variable using regex

Tags: regex, bash

I need to find similarly named strings that are passed as bash variables to a regex pattern in an interpolated string as a function argument. I'm new to Regex so am unsure what the best approach is.

Here's what I currently have:

**bash_script.sh**

```sh
findKeys(`grep --ignore-case ^${apiServiceName}$`)
```

However, some APIs have similar names, eg:

```
apiServiceNames = ['api-name', 'api-name-one', 'api-name-two']
```

The confusing bit is where to put `\` (which characters to escape) as I need `${}` for the variable but `$^` opens and closes a string.

Comment: I have a list of similar API names. They're passed to the script as variables. I can show the variable as `grep --ignore-case ^$stackName` but this would only find `api-name` not api-name-one` or `api-name-two`. Is that clearer?

Comment: It should allow all of them, but it's finding the first and then stopping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex match with `grep` or any third party tools. The native `bash` shell provides strong enough features for pattern matching. For e.g. the below construct when written as

```
if [[ $apiServiceName == api-name?(?(-)+(one|two)) ]]; then
    printf '%s - is allowed\n' "$apiServiceName"
fi
```

The construct `api-name?(?(-)+(one|two))` is an extended glob match syntax provided by the shell, that is enabled by default when `[[..]]` is used for pattern matching with the `==` operator. See more on [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)